# Retrofit - Login Authentication (token)

Tags: android

I have an API for login authentication. The end of that API path is like this: /api/authentication/login post[login, password, fcm_token]
How should I write my code for use this API path with Retrofit. I don't understand this API path. Please advice me.

Comment: Looks like you have mixed the API path with payload and method.
Path: "/api/authentication/login"             METHOD: "POST"          Payload: login, password, fcm_token

Comment: Lukas Novicky,  I didn't write codes related to retrofit and it's my first time. I don't have any idea about what I should do. If you used path like this, can you show some code of yours for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add this "/api/authentication/" in your base url.

in your ApiInterface class:-

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @POST("login")
    Call<YourModleClass> loginUser(@Query("login") String login, @Query("password") String password, @Query("fcm_token") String fcm_token);
```

Comment: `POST` request and you are passing it `Query` parameters  strange

Comment: you can create here a model class and pass in @Body. in model class you have to create these 3 variables like:-   String login, String password , String fcm_token. and create a constructor in model class.

Comment: That's great. What's the next step?